# How to make the date format take the form as DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, date-format, date-formatting

I am using SharePoint 2016, and InfoPath designer 2013. 
In InfoPath form, I added a textbox that has Data Type as Date. 
I changed the formatting of the date to use the English(united kingdom) which will take the form as DD/MM/YYYY. 
When I preview the form in InfoPath filler the date format is working fine. 
but when I publish the form to document library and open the form from the browser. the date take DD/MM/YYYY format. 
In SharePoint site setting, under site administration, in regional setting I changed the locale to English(United Kingdom). 
when again I run the form again still i see M/D/YYYY format. 
My question is how to make the date format take the form as DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: It may take a moment to take effect after changing the Locale.

Comment: yes, you're right. it needed some time.

Comment: Good, Please Mark your question as Solved